# Как добавить анимацию в уже отрисованный виджет PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, анимация, pyqt, qparallelanimationgroup

Пытаю добавить третью анимацию, в уже запущенную программу, для этого использую методы родительского класса, `self.update()`, `self.repaint()`, но анимация не добавляется. 
Что я делаю не так?

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QPropertyAnimation, QParallelAnimationGroup, QRect, QEasingCurve
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys

class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap("icon.png"))
          
class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.i = 0
        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label.move(0, 0)
        self.label2 = Label(self)
        self.label2.move(0, 0)
        self.animation1 = QPropertyAnimation(self.label, b'geometry')
        self.animation2 = QPropertyAnimation(self.label2, b'geometry')
        
        self.group = QParallelAnimationGroup(self)               
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation1)
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation2)

        
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.move_label)
        self.timer.start(1000)
    

    def add_tag(self):
        self.label3 = Label(self)
        self.label3.move(0, 0)
        self.animation3 = QPropertyAnimation(self.label3, b'geometry')
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation3)
        self.animation3.setStartValue(QRect(self.label3.pos().x() + 20, self.label3.pos().y() + 
        30, 100, 30))
        self.animation3.setEndValue(QRect(self.label3.pos().x() + 50, self.label3.pos().x() + 60, 
        100, 30))
        self.animation3.setLoopCount(1)
        
        #self.group.updateDirection()

    def move_label(self):
        self.i += 1
        if self.i == 2:
            self.i = 0
            self.add_tag()
            print(self.group.animationCount())
        
        self.animation1.setStartValue(QRect(self.label.pos().x(), self.label.pos().y(), 100, 30))
        self.animation1.setEndValue(QRect(self.label.pos().x() + 30, self.label.pos().y() + 40, 
         100, 30))
        self.animation1.setLoopCount(1)
        #self.animation1.setDuration(1000)
        #self.animation1.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.OutBounce)
        

        self.animation2.setStartValue(QRect(self.label2.pos().x(), self.label2.pos().y(), 100, 
        30))
        self.animation2.setEndValue(QRect(self.label2.pos().x() + 40, self.label2.pos().y() + 50, 
        100, 30))
        self.animation2.setLoopCount(1)
        #self.animation2.setDuration(1000)                                      # 8000
        #self.animation2.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.CosineCurve)
        
        
        self.group.start()
        #self.label.move(self.point)
        #self.label2.move(self.point2)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Main()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: эту информацию стоит указывать непосредственно в теле вопроса, а не в комментариях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понимаю анимацию, которую вы хотите показать.

Вот вам некоторые рекомендации:

- если вы создаете объект виджета не в конструкторе и
  хотите после его создания показать,
  то надо добавить его в менеджер компоновки или
  выполните `self.label3.show()`, 
  т.е. показать его.
- если вы динамический создаете объект виджета (`self.label3 = Label(self)`),
  то не нужно делать этот объект атрибутом класса, достаточно так
  (`label3 = Label(self)`)
- при входе в метод `add_tag(self)`,
  вы создаете экземпляр `label3` и все време устанавливаете его в
  `label3.move(0, 0)`. Вы действительно этого хотите?
- проверьте строку:

  ```
  # ------------------------------------------------------------> v <------ ???
  #           QRect(self.label3.pos().x() + 50, self.label3.pos().x() + 60,
  ```

---

---

Попробуйте так:

```
...

   def add_tag(self):
       label3 = Label(self)
       label3.move(0, 0)                                        # ??? 
       label3.show()                                            # !!! +++
       
       self.animation3 = QPropertyAnimation(label3, b'geometry')
       self.group.addAnimation(self.animation3)
       self.animation3.setStartValue(
           QRect(label3.pos().x() + 20, label3.pos().y() + 
               30, 100, 30))
       self.animation3.setEndValue(
# ------------------------------------------------------------> v <------ ???
#           QRect(self.label3.pos().x() + 50, self.label3.pos().x() + 60, 
           QRect(label3.pos().x() + 50, label3.pos().y() + 60, 
               100, 30))
       self.animation3.setLoopCount(1) # ???

...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]